# How to add a view (circular progress bar for example) relative to another view in a tablelayout

Tags: java, android, android-studio

hope someone can advise.

I have created an Android app in Android studio that dynamically and programmatically adds a load of buttons into a tablelayout. The number of buttons is set by the user so there could be 1 or there could be 100. Using the tablelayout they are added neatly two buttons to each row and are sized correctly. I am happy with this.

I would like to add another view (in the form of a circular progress bar) in front of each button so that when the button is pressed the circle rotates while whatever the button has been setup to do is actioned. I want the progress bar to preferably sit in the middle of the button but I'm not overly fussy.

Can I get some advice as to the best way to achieve this? Do I need to redo my buttons in a relative layout? Is there some way of adding views on top of other views in a table layout? Any advice or suggestions welcome.

Thank you

My current button code...

(It assumes that there are two buttons on each row and you know the number of rows and number of buttons).

```
   TableLayout.LayoutParams tableParams = new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
   TableRow.LayoutParams rowParams = new TableRow.LayoutParams(0, android.widget.TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 3f);


   TableLayout tableLayout = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.thetablelayout);
   tableLayout.removeAllViews();

   for (int i = 0; i < NumberOfRows; i++) {


        TableRow tableRow = new TableRow(this);
        tableRow.setLayoutParams(tableParams);

        Button btnOne = new Button(this);
        btnOne.setId(1001 + i);
        Button btnTwo = new Button(this);
        btnTwo.setId(2001 + i);


        btnOne.setLayoutParams(rowParams);
        btnTwo.setLayoutParams(rowParams);

        tableRow.addView(btnOne);

        View adivider = new View(this);
        adivider.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(20, TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        adivider.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);


   // This bit of code deals with odd/even numbers of buttons. 

        if (((i + 1) * 2) < NumberOfButtons + 1) {
            tableRow.addView(adivider);
            tableRow.addView(btnTwo);
            btnTwo.setOnClickListener(mGlobal_OnClickListener);
            btnTwo.setOnLongClickListener(mGlobal_OnLONGClickListener);
            btnTwo.setTextSize(14);
            btnTwo.setSingleLine(true);
            btnTwo.setTextColor(0xFFFFFFFF);
            btnTwo.setText(btnnamearray.get((i * 2) + 1));
            btnTwo.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.buttonright);
        } else {
            tableRow.addView(adivider);
            btnTwo.setBackgroundResource(android.R.color.transparent);
            tableRow.addView(btnTwo);
        }


        View aline3 = new View(this);
        aline3.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 20));
        aline3.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);


        tableLayout.addView(tableRow);

        tableLayout.addView(aline3);
   }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you mentioned, I'd suggest redoing the buttons as relative layouts, which would allow you nest a ProgressBar(set to visibility="gone") in each button-view. I'd be happy to help further if you post your code.

EDIT: Okay I mocked this up for you. Take time to read it all, especially the comments!

RESULT:   onClick shows the ProgressBar, onLongClick hides it
[image]

```
    private void setupTableLayout(int NumberOfRows, int NumberOfButtons){
        TableLayout.LayoutParams tableParams = new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        TableRow.LayoutParams rowParams = new TableRow.LayoutParams(0, android.widget.TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 3f);


        TableLayout tableLayout = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.thetablelayout);
        tableLayout.removeAllViews();

        for (int i = 0; i < NumberOfRows; i++) {
            TableRow tableRow = new TableRow(this);
            tableRow.setLayoutParams(tableParams);

            RelativeLayout btnOneLayout = (RelativeLayout)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_button, null);
            RelativeLayout btnTwoLayout = (RelativeLayout)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_button, null);

            ProgressBar btnOneProgressBar = (ProgressBar)btnOneLayout.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
            ProgressBar btnTwoProgressBar = (ProgressBar)btnTwoLayout.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

            Button btnOne = (Button)btnOneLayout.findViewById(R.id.button);
            btnOne.setText("Btn 1, Row " + i);
            btnOne.setId(1001 + i);
            Button btnTwo = (Button)btnTwoLayout.findViewById(R.id.button);
            btnTwo.setText("Btn 2, Row " + i);
            btnTwo.setId(2001 + i);

/*            btnOne.setLayoutParams(rowParams);   //Weight for width set in Layout file on RelativeLayout
            btnTwo.setLayoutParams(rowParams);*/

            setButtonClickListener(btnOneLayout, btnOneProgressBar);
            setButtonLongClickListener(btnOneLayout, btnOneProgressBar);

            tableRow.addView(btnOneLayout); //Add layout, instead of just Button

            //Is this done as an invisible separator? You can instead just use Margin on above/below views
            View adivider = new View(this);
            adivider.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(20, TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
            adivider.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

            // This bit of code deals with odd/even numbers of buttons.
            if (((i + 1) * 2) < NumberOfButtons + 1) {
                tableRow.addView(adivider);
                tableRow.addView(btnTwoLayout);

                //Click listeners
                setButtonClickListener(btnTwoLayout, btnTwoProgressBar);
                setButtonLongClickListener(btnTwoLayout, btnTwoProgressBar);

/*                btnTwo.setTextSize(14);              //If true for all buttons, can be done in Layout file
                btnTwo.setSingleLine(true);
                btnTwo.setTextColor(0xFFFFFFFF);*/

                //btnTwo.setText(getButtonName((i * 2) + 1));
                //btnTwo.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.buttonright); //I didn't have this drawable
            } else {
                tableRow.addView(adivider);

                btnTwoLayout.setBackgroundResource(android.R.color.transparent); //I changed this to overall layout, not sure if this is what you want
                //btnTwoLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); //Or View.GONE   //Perhaps you want this instead

                tableRow.addView(btnTwoLayout);
            }

            //Is this done as an invisible separator? You can instead just use Margin/Padding on above/below views
            View aline3 = new View(this);
            aline3.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 20));
            aline3.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

            tableLayout.addView(tableRow);
            tableLayout.addView(aline3);
        }

    }

    private String getButtonName(int position){
        String name = "";
        switch (position){
            case 0:
                name = "Bob";
                break;
            case 1:
                name = "Jim";
                break;
            default:
                name = "Default";
                break;
        }
        return name;
    }

    private void setButtonClickListener(RelativeLayout layout, final ProgressBar progressBar){
        layout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //Do something
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });
    }
    private void setButtonLongClickListener(RelativeLayout layout, final ProgressBar progressBar){
        layout.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                //Do something
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
```

Call the function with what you desire...

```
setupTableLayout(10, 2);
```

And the necessary Layout files

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/thetablelayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        </TableLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

custom_button.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
    android:padding="24dp">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
        android:text="Button"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:clickable="false">
    </Button>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:visibility="gone"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Good luck, and don't be afraid to ask further questions. :-)

Comment: Thank you for the advice. The code I already have that creates the buttons is now included in the original post. If you can advise how I can achieve the same results in a relative layout that would be really appreciated.

Comment: @Regnodulous  Unsure if it sends you notification for Edit, so I'll do this as well.

Comment: Wow - that's absolutely amazing and exactly what I needed. Thank you so much for taking the time to show me. I'll try this tonight. Many many thanks again. You are a gent.

Comment: Thank you again for your help but I wonder if I could impose a little more. I have mocked this up exactly as you have shown me but I can't for the life of me get the Progress bars to appear. I've even tried setting the visibility to visible in the XML file but no progress bars are shown. I know the onclick events are working because I added a toast just to pop up a message to prove it but all I get when I run the code above is the buttons. Thank you

Comment: Ok - figured part of it out. If I make the button background transparent I can then see the progressbar. Weird. Will do some more tinkering first. Thank you

Comment: Someone else answered this for me so can't take the credit but the answer thus...

Comment: You are propably running this on android >= 5.0. In 5.0 they added elevation field for views. Elevation defines z-order of views in ViewGroup. Add elevation <ProgressBar
    ...
    android:elevation="10dp"/>

Comment: I was running Android 4.2 I think, definitely not 5. It might be where ProgressBars defined in Xml, because it could be behind the button if you don't have it the same way in my example code. @Regnodulous

Comment: Hello phial. Your code was fine. I was running it in 5 not you. I just posted the answer someone else gave me in another question in case it was useful for someone else and it all worked with your code. Thank you again!!!

Comment: No problem! I enjoyed helping you.